# [Odoo][V9]Show taxes on sale order

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9

I want to show all taxes on sale order.

So i have to connections :

- **sale.order** to **sale.order.line** : a *One2many*, with inverse_name =
  **order_id**
- **sale.order.line** to **account.tax** : a Many2many.

My question is how to connect **sale.order** with **account.tax**?

Thank you.

Comment: All ready there, why you want I think not using there dear

Comment: You need then you can do there like sale.order.line to account.tax : a Many2many.

Comment: Hi,
I tried different way :
*tax_line_ids = fields.Many2many('account.tax', 'account_tax_sale_order_line_rel', 'account_tax_id', 'sale_order_line_id')*

and

*test = fields.Many2many('account.tax')*

Nothing works

Answer (score 0):

Ftk,

Their could be multiple possible solutions depending on your requirements.

- First you can create regular M2M field **tax_id** and you can manually select tax.
- Second solution could be create comoute M2M field which will take tax from order lines and link to sale order for later use.

Theirs could be more solution based on what excellently you need.

**EDIT**

For getting tax per line item, you can call method [`_amount_line_tax`](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/addons/sale/sale.py#L48) on `sale.order` this will calculate tax for given lines. SO you can have tax by lines. And if you want to calculate for every tax for every lines then create two for loop

```
for line in sale.oder_line
   for tax in line.tax_id
       call _amount_line_tax here to get tax per line.
```

Above code will help you calculate tax per tax per line and then you can do math to sum up all similar taxes.

Hope this will help.

Bests,

Comment: Hi @shodowsjedi,
I think that i forgot to precise one think : I would like to have total amount of taxes per different taxes.
I'm not sure to understand *the first solution*, you mean to add a M2M field **tax_ids** in **sale.order** model ? But how could I retrieve total amount of taxes for each taxes?
For the *second solution*, I wont have the total amount of taxes.

Bests

Comment: @FTK Yeah you are right I misunderstood at first point. but I edited answer based on new facts you gave